# Getting a "Commit from Multiple Working Copies" message.. not sure what to do?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I opened a project yesterday via Open From Subversion

I accidentally saved the project to C:\Users\blahblah....

I then immediately closed the project, and Opened From Subversion again, saving it to the correct directory.

Now I'm trying to commit the changes I made since opening the correct project and I'm getting this message:

[image: Commit from Multiple Working Copies]

Is there a risk that I can screw things up if I deselect C:\etc and instead select D:\etc and commit that?

There are no changes to the C:\ project. Also, I now have to merge the changes from yesterday into another branch.

Answer (score 1):

This dialog appears whenever more than one working copy is involved and is mostly seen when changing your code and an external. It means it will commit your code and the external separate because this is dealt like different working copies and so this must be done.

In your case your solution was partly saved somewhere else making a second working copy (from the same repository). Guess you did the right think when deleting the mistakenly created files.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the C:... solution. It seems to have done the trick because the D:.. solution committed ok after that.